# azure blob storage nodejs v10 - Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

Env:

- nodejs 10.15.2, express 4.16.4
- happens on azure app service as well as local test env
- using "@azure/storage-blob": "^10.3.0"

I'm creating an express app to up/download blobs to/from azure blob storage.
Everything works fine: Can upload blobs, set metadata, download blobs etc.
But: When the aborter(s) run into their timeout, they cause an ancaught excpetion which terminates the node process.

The error stack is:

```
Fri Apr 19 2019 07:38:28 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: The request was aborted
    at new RestError (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:1397:28)
    at a.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mql\node_modules\@azure\storage-blob\dist\index.js:1:11269)
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mql\node_modules\@azure\storage-blob\dist\index.js:1:1277
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at a.abort (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mql\node_modules\@azure\storage-blob\dist\index.js:1:1255)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mql\node_modules\@azure\storage-blob\dist\index.js:1:519)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at unrefdHandle (timers.js:520:7)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:222:12)
```

In my local dev-env I put a breakpoint on uncaught exception and found:

- Event is finally thrown in event.js (emit)
- It is caused by RetriableReadableStream, (@azure/storage-blob/dist/esm/lib/utils/RetriableReadableStream), see "aborter.addEventListener":

```
    function RetriableReadableStream(aborter, source, getter, offset, count, options) {
        if (options === void 0) { options = {}; }
        var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
        _this.retries = 0;
        _this.aborter = aborter;
        _this.getter = getter;
        _this.source = source;
        _this.start = offset;
        _this.offset = offset;
        _this.end = offset + count - 1;
        _this.maxRetryRequests =
            options.maxRetryRequests && options.maxRetryRequests >= 0
                ? options.maxRetryRequests
                : 0;
        _this.progress = options.progress;
        _this.options = options;
        aborter.addEventListener("abort", function () {
            _this.source.pause();
            _this.emit("error", new RestError("The request was aborted", RestError.REQUEST_ABORTED_ERROR));
        });
...
```

- Which in turn is caused by the aborter:

```
    Aborter.prototype.abort = function () {
        var _this = this;
        if (this.aborted) {
            return;
        }
        this.cancelTimer();
        if (this.onabort) {
            this.onabort.call(this);
        }
        this.abortEventListeners.forEach(function (listener) {
            listener.call(_this);
        });
        this.children.forEach(function (child) { return child.cancelByParent(); });
        this._aborted = true;
    };
```

My Aborter is created like this:

```
    createAborter(): Aborter {
        let aborter = Aborter.timeout(5 * ONE_MINUTE);
        aborter.onabort = () => {
            console.warn(`AzureBlog.createAborter.onAbort: Request was aborted.`);
        }
        return aborter;
    }
```

... and my download looks like this:

```
    async download(blobName: string): Promise<NodeJS.ReadableStream> {
        const blockBlobURL = this.getBlockBlobUrl(blobName);
        const downloadResponse = await blockBlobURL.download(this.createAborter(), 0);
        if (!downloadResponse) {
            throw new Error(`Download returned undefined.`);
        }
        if (!downloadResponse.readableStreamBody) {
            throw new Error(`downloadResponse.readableStreamBody is undefined.`);
        }
        return downloadResponse.readableStreamBody;
    }
```

... and I stream it to the client like this:

```
self.expressApp.route('/download')
    .get(jsonParser, async (req: Request, resp: Response) => {
      handleDownload(req, resp);
    }).post(jsonParser, async (req: Request, resp: Response) => {
      handleDownload(req, resp);
    });

    ...

      let blobReadStream = await self.azureBlobStore.download(id);
      blobReadStream.pipe(resp);
```

As mentioned, everything works fine until the timeout. What I don't get is:

- Why would someone throw an uncaught error in a base-library whithout allowing the lib-consumers to catch it? (Btw, had the same problem with azure gremlin nodejs)
- My aborter "onAbort()" just adds another event-listener. Do I have to remove all the other listeners to prevent that error?
- Why are the "abort" listeners fired at all? All requests (download, upstream etc.) work fine within seconds. The samples/docu does not say anything about manually destroying/disabling the aborter after a sucessfull request.

I assume that I have misunderstood the Aborter-conecpt. So any help is much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-js/issues/67 - just stumbled on it myself. Couldn't say if it works since my problem is not really reproducable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will give it a try!

Comment: It worked, the exceptions are gone. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can add your solution as the answer. It can be beneficial to others.